# Object is not being rendered properly at at medium+ distance (Eevee vs. Cycles?)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I created an astronaut floating in space, he's working fine. Then, in a separate .blend project, I created a galaxy to float behind the astronaut. I used append to add the galaxy to the astronaut scene. It should be located way behind the astronaut, but I noticed it wasn't rendering at all. It wouldn't even show in the workspace unless I zoom way in.

When I try to render an image, it fails. Can't see the galaxy at all *unless* I place it *directly* in front of the camera, but this can't work, since it needs to be in the distance, and even up close, it's not rendering correctly.

This might have to do with Eevee! If I switch to "cycles" it seems to work, but the time it takes to render is not acceptable. I mean, the astronaut is *animated* and renders a video in a few seconds. The galaxy takes several minutes to produce an image (in cycles mode, that is... in Eevee it doesn't render at all).

**Below** is an image of the galaxy *not* rendering in the viewport. If I switched to Cycles you would actually see it.

**My question:** Is there an Eevee setting that will allow me to render this object? Or is there some other setting I'm getting badly wrong? Maybe the galaxy object's emission that will allow it to be seen at a greater distance?
(I already set the camera's clipping distance high and it still doesn't render)

[image]

If it helps, here's me switching from Eevee to Cycles and it renders perfectly, but this won't work for me creating multiple clips
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkLRd.jpg

Edit:

Another example, I found the vertical plane a few feet behind my astronaut,  where Eevee simple stops trying to render. I angled the galaxy so only half of it shows because the rest is just not rendered at all

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share a simplified version of your file so that we can test (don't forget to pack the images, and copy paste the link you'll get from the site): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

for cycles to render something there has to be light, (put the texture in an emission shader makes it a light). but if you put it real far away then the emission might need to be stronger as well.

Oh and you seam to do something with fog/volumetrics, be aware then that it eats light as well if its far away you wont be able to see it, i dont think fog exist in space instead you got sharp light with hard shadows.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I would LOVE if I didn't need to use Cycles. But in Eevee, the object doesn't render at all (unless the camera is right next to it, which I can't do). Is there any way I can "increase the emission" in Eevee? I'm not sure if that's the right terminology, It just doesn't render at all at distance, and I need to... make it more visible? prioritize it?

Comment: Increasing the emission is definitely not the right terminology. I did that, and it makes the galaxy brighter, however, it still simply doesn't render if it's more than a couple feet away from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

increase the clip distance. This works for objects in both eevee and cycles, but in eevee you have to increase the clip distance for volumetrics separately. This is done in settings, under volumetrics. simply increase the end slider until you can see your object